# How to open jscoverage results inside WebStorm

Tags: javascript, tdd, code-coverage, mocha.js, webstorm

I'm able to run jscoverage ok and generate the html reports (including sending the reports to coveralls.

What I really would like next is to be able to open those results inside WebStorm, but at the moment it only seems to support Karma or JsTestDriver (see https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/monitoring-code-coverage-for-javascript.html)

Am I missing something obvious?

Coveralls use lcov data (from mocha-lcov-reporter), maybe there is a way to load/show lcov data inside webstorm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So at the moment (jan 2015) this doesn't seem to be possible.

Also confirmed by this answer [Is there a way to load the lcov data inside webstorm?](https://github.com/StevenLooman/mocha-lcov-reporter/issues/6) (on mocha-lcov-reporter repo)